# How to change text visibility on android application

Tags: java, android, visibility

im a student and i'm working on my first andorid  app.
I want to create e button that can hide and show a text, so i've wrote this on fragment :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="36dp" 
     android:text="@string/t1"
     android:visibility="invisible"/>

  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton2" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
          android:onClick="click_button1"
          android:src="@drawable/pippo"
         android:text="@string/s1" />
```

and this on main:

```
 public void click_button1 (View view){ 
        TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
           textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
```

on main what can i use to change visibility?!

Comment: what's the error or exception you are getting ?

Comment: there's no error, i want to change text by pressing button, if text is visible invisible, and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out for visible and invisible the `TextView` on your `Button` click.

```
 public void click_button1 (View view){ 
        TextView textview=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
          if(!textview.isShown())  //Check if the view is currently visible or not.
             textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         else
             textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }
```

Comment: just one warning on TextView textview=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
on parent, i erase it and it works too!

Answer (score 0):

Make the view View.GONE  on your xml layout. Because it  won't take the memory in your activity. You can verify this by hierarchyviewer. Once you click the button make the button visibility gone and make your text view visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
boolean bool=false;
         TextView textview;
         ViewGroup parent;

             parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
             textview=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                public void click_button1 (View view){ 

              if(bool){
                      textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      bool=true;
              }else{
                    textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    bool=false;
                }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Google [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) says:

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for
>   layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for
>   layout purposes.